# Problems with NuGet Packages on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, maui, nuget-package

I'm developing a project for an app in .NET MAUI (using a SQL local Server), and basically I'm with problems with the NuGet packages. I need to use some of them (as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens, and others), but even though I downloaded them erros like "The type or namespace name '*NuGet Package name*' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'" and "There was no runtime pack for *NuGet Package name*
available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'maccatalyst x-64'" keep appearing.

I spend a few days asking to ChatGPT what to do, and even cleaning the solution, downloading everything again, repairing the Visual Studio, updating everything and deleting the 'obj' and 'bin' folders, the problems continue.

Can someone help me?

Comment: When you say you "downloaded them", do you mean using right click project/solution > Manage NuGet packages?

Comment: Yes, and also on the Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console

Comment: You are making MAC OS application?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer) doesn't seem to be intended for use in frontend applications. Dependency Injection already comes built in, so you shouldn't need [Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection), see *GitHub repositories*, MAUI is one of the top-listed users of this package. The same goes for other packages you mentioned. However, it's also not clear what exactly you're doing.